# file upload processing file from xhr to web api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the following code to upload file to the server,

**Javascript:**

```
      function FileUpload(ServerName) {
alert("Entering File Change...");

    var file = this.file1[0];
    alert("File Change");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.file = file; // not necessary if you create scopes like this
    xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
        alert("progress");

        var done = e.position || e.loaded, total = e.totalSize || e.total;
        console.log('xhr progress: ' + (Math.floor(done/total*1000)/10) + '%');
    }, false);
    if ( xhr.upload ) {
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
            var done = e.position || e.loaded, total = e.totalSize || e.total;
            console.log('xhr.upload progress: ' + done + ' / ' + total + ' = ' +   (Math.floor(done/total*1000)/10) + '%');
        };
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if ( 4 == this.readyState ) {
            console.log(['xhr upload complete', e]);
        }
    };
    xhr.open('post', "http://localhost:49868/UploadFile/" + ServerName, true);
    xhr.send(file);

     }
```

**Web api code:**

```
       [HttpPost]
       [ActionName("UploadFile")]
       public HttpResponseMessage UploadFile(string servername)
       {  
      try
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",  "*");

            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            HttpResponseMessage result = null;

            // Check if files are available
            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var files = new List<string>();

                // interate the files and save on the server
                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                    //var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + postedFile.FileName);
                    postedFile.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\New folder (4)\\" + postedFile.FileName);

                    //files.Add(filePath);
                    //File.Copy(filePath, RootPath + postedFile.FileName);
                    //File.Delete(filePath);
                }

                // return result
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, files);
            }
            else
            {
                // return BadRequest (no file(s) available)
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

           return result;

          }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

      }
```

**My Question is how to handle this on the server side, i.e in the web api, how to get the file there on the server and store it in some specific location?**

Now the `httpRequest.Files` is returned null, where to get the file and save it?